# Binding data in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom control `myCustomControl.Xaml`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox Name="myCustomComboBoxParent"
          someId = "{Binding customId}"
          .../>
```

And a cs file `myCustomControl.xaml.cs`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty customIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(customIdProperty), typeof(string), typeof(myClass),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        "", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public string customId
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(customIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(customIdProperty, value); }
}
```

And then I have `mainPage.xaml` where I set `customId`

```
<local:customComboBox x:Name="myCustomComboBoxChild1" customId = "someIdToBeSended" .../>
```

I dont understand why is my `customId` not send from `mainPage.xaml` to `myCustromControl.xaml`? What I am doing wrong? (`ComboBox` has no id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Binding Does Not Work

A dependency property is *defined on the control itself*. A regular binding without an explicit source uses the current `DataContext`. In order to make your binding work, you would have to set the `DataContext` to the control itself. Although you can do this in the constructor using `DataContext=this;`, you **should not do** it, otherwise the custom control will not inherit its data context from parents.

What you should do instead is specify the control as source in your binding. You can do this by assigning an `x:Name` to your control and then using [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to refer to it.

```
<UserControl ...
             x:Name="This">
    <Grid>
       <ComboBox SomeProperty="{Binding customId, ElementName=This}"
                 .../>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Alternatively, you can specify a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) with the custom control type.

```
<ComboBox SomeProperty="{Binding customId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:myCustomControl}}"
          .../>
```

### Dependency Property Definition

Your dependency property definition is wrong.

- A dependency property must fit the pattern `<Name>Property` and its wrapper property must be named `<Name>`. The name of the wrapper property, *not* the dependency property is passed as first parameter. Although this does not have an effect in your concrete scenario, it will cause issues later.
- The owner type must be the type of the control where the dependecy property is defined. Here it is `typeof(myClass)`, but must be `typeof(myCustomControl)`.

In summary, the dependecy property should be declared like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty customIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   nameof(customId), typeof(string), typeof(myCustomControl),
   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Another remark on naming. In C# you should adhere to Pascal-Casing for classes (and therefore controls, too) and properties. Pascal-cased identifiers start with a capital letter, e.g. `MyCustomControl`, `CustomIdProperty` and `CustomId`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `nameof(customIdProperty)` with `nameof(customId)`, and `typeof(myClass)`  with `typeof(myCustomControl)`

Comment: As described by @thatguy, this is only half the answer.